# Adding openCV .dll files to Netbeans C++ Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, dll, netbeans

I am developing software where I need to use the OpenCV libraries under NetBeans. Took 2 days to be able to run correctly a C++ Application with OpenCV.

In a C++ Application I needed to add C:/OpenCV245/build/include in project properties->Build->C++ compiler-> Include Directories and Headers. Also, Under the Linker properties-> Additional Library Directories  I had to add the following directories

- C:/OpenCV245/release/lib
- C:/OpenCV245/build/x64/mingw/lib

  and add the .dll files I specifically needed in the linker->libraries

Now when I try to create a C++ Qt application, I add the proper include directories and headers but  I can't add the path to my "additional libraries"...

I tried building to see what errors would pop:

> cannot find -lopencv_core245.dll 
> cannot find -lopencv_highgui245.dll

How do we add .dll.a files to a C++ Qt application under Netbeans?

---

Programming environment:

- NetBeans 7.4
- MinGW 3.2 Compiler c++ compiler, msys make command and qt5.1.1 qmake for Qmake Command
- Qt5.1.1
- OpenCV2.4.5
- Windows 8 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+Under **Project Properties-> Build -> Qt** go to Expert Custom Definitions add add the path to the appropriate .dll.a files with the LIBS +=

+Under **Project Properties-> Build -> C++ Compiler** in *Include Directories and Headers* add the appropriate path for the includes. ex: C:\OpenCV\build\include

+Under **Project Properties-> Build -> Linker** click on Libraries then Add Library File... ( NOT ADD LIBRARY) and add the appropriate .dll.a files that were included in the first point.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are trying to link with the *.DLL files instead of *.LIB files. The right way to go is to:

1. In the linker->libraries settings link to the *.LIB files you need instead of the *.DLL files.
2. Compile your program so you get an *.EXE
3. Put the relevant *.DLL-files in the same folder as the *.EXE
4. The program is now runnable if you double-click its icon in the file browser.

It the program refuses to run from Netbeans but it works from the file browser, then that is because you need to tell Netbeans what the "current working directory" is when you launch the program in debug mode. This setting should be available in some settings dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the lib files that are given with the library are compiled to work with Visual Studio. I had to compile the source files from scratch and all that is available are the .dll files

Comment: Lib files are not compiled to work with a specific IDE or compiler. The only difference comes from compiling them for a different OS or computer architecture (i.e. 32bit versus 64bit systems). If the lib files were compiled on your system, with mostly any compiler, then they should work.

Comment: OP does not link to `.DLL` files . OP links to `.a` files. e.g. `libopencv_highgui245.dll.a`

Comment: @moskito-x thank you, but when i add them the compiler can't find them. I put the .dll.a the same way as I mentioned in the question and it does not work. It works in a C++ application under netbeans, but when I try it in a C++ QT application, it fails